# Brewer's Friend one gallon equipment profile

Tags: equipment, recipe-scaling

I'm a newbie one-gallon brewer (done 4 batches as for now). I tried several recipe sources and now I'm trying out the [Brewer's Friend](https://www.brewersfriend.com). 
The thing is that most of the recipes are 5+ gallon batches so I'm going to use Scale function which as I understood requires Equipment profile to be properly configured. 
Could someone recommend what the optimal settings should be? Or maybe you could share what do you use for your equipment.

Here's my setup:

- 10-quarts wide stainless steel boil kettle
- 2-gallon Igloo cooler mash tun
- I do sparge/lauter by just pouring out all the stuff on the strainer
- Simple one-gallon glass fermenter.

Thanks. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**The equipment profile is just used for your Efficiency calculations. Mash efficiency and brew house efficiency.**

These really have little to do with scaling down a recipe.

The only concern would be more rapid boil off with the lesser volume, which can be adjusted with the flame or adding water to correct if you had more than exected evaporation.

Set your Efficiency to 75-80% for mash, and 90% brew house. You really won't have your numbers until you brew on the system and calculate them.

**Mash efficiency** has more to do with technique than equipment. Equipment that allows a finer crush, grain pressing, minimizing false bottom grain free space will increase mash efficiency.

**Brew house efficiency** mainly concerns volume loss. You have a simple system so 90-95% is expected. Volume loss is usually wort that's left behind in the wet grain, mash tun, kettle, lines, pumps. Fermentor also plays a roll, some are better at compacting trub giving more end volume of beer.

Brewers friend combines these efficiencies into one value. For a total Brew house efficiency. Since your system will have little to no volume loss. You can safely just take 10% off your mash efficiency to get your Brew house Efficiency. So if you get 85% mass eff, set the Brew house value to 75%.
https://www.brewersfriend.com/faq/#brewsessions5

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm, it's interesting but this profile thing is still bothering me since total 'Water Requirements' (Mash volume, Sparge volume) has up to 0.5 gal difference depending on equipment profile configs.

Comment: @Dmytro use the fermentor setting. Most 5-15g systems will boil off 1 gallon per hour, but varies a lot on volume, pot size and burner btu. Since you've brewed on this system before you should know this value for your preboil ,post boil values.